# How to find rowindex when clicked a button in table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to find row which clicked button in.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo 1</td>
    <td><input  type="button" value="Remove" id="remove1"/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo 2 </td>
    <td><input  type="button" value="Remove" id="remove2"/> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My table struct is like above.  Normally I can us buttonid to get row index. But If I remove a row (tr) another row index changes. For example:

If I remove first row with jQuery, second row index changes as 0 then I cannot use button's id. (remove - 2 )

Well I think that I must use parent function but it doesn't work.

```
var elem = $('#remove2');
alert(elem.parent()[0].sectionRowIndex);
```

I tried this one but doesn't work. I need row index that clicked button in the row.

I hope that I explained my issue.

Comment: u can set the new attr like rowid in your <input> tag or <td> tag.   then you can get value like : $("#remove1").attr("rowid")

Comment: I create rows dynamically, yes i can set an id to rows but closest functions looks better. thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("table tr input").on('click', function(e){
   alert($(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zwHK4/)

Answer (score 6):

Try using this: http://jsfiddle.net/jd9N4/1/

```
var elem = $('input[type="button"]');
$(elem).click(function() {
   alert($(this).closest('tr').index());
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: How do I target specific table?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `ID`

```
$('table').on('click', 'input[value="Remove"]', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: what if I have more than one table?

Comment: how do I target specific table?

Comment: by using your table ID inside the selector. Remember CSS selectors? i.e: `'#myTable input[etc...` @codegrid

Comment: During add row, I pushed the values for the newly created row into a list and on remove row used splice with the row index to remove from the list. Not working properly. Is there a better way?

Comment: @codegrid sure there is, use the `.on()` method with event delegation: `$('#myTable').on('click', 'input[value=Remove]', function(){`

Answer (score 2):

IF you are adding row dynamically you can

```
 $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
     var indexRow = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
     document.getElementById("table-name").deleteRow(indexRow);
 });
```